# What elements can ng-disabled be applied to?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, events

I thought I could apply `ng-disabled` to an `<a>` element. It's looking like I can't. It works on the `<button>` element. Does anyone know what elements I can apply `ng-disabled` to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could not disable anchor tag. `ng-disabled` or `disabled` attribute only work on the `button/input`s element, If you want to disable anchor tag then you should have call `ng-click` function on it & then on basis of it either redirect or don't do anything.

**Markup**

```
<a href="" ng-click="redirect(isValid, url)"> Anchor Button </a>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.redirect = function(isValid, url){
    if(isValid)
      $window.open(url, "_blank")
}
```

Comment: disabled works on input also, not just button. In older browsers you actually could disable `<a>`

Comment: @charlietfl Oh i missed input element..do you think any alterative way to make anchor disable and enable..Thanks

Comment: @charlietfl then what will happen about the click handler..how could we disable them?

Comment: pointer events is not safe to use _yet_ if you care about cross browser compatibility esp IE<=10. True disable property is applicable to these [form controls](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#disabled-elements)

Comment: @charlietfl It works for IE11+  & you for svg it will work in IE9

Comment: what's wierd is MDN claims more coverage than caniuse

Comment: @charlietfl i dont think so. Probably you are looking at the SVG row in MDN?

Comment: @PSL oops yes... strange they have 2 properties on same page.

Comment: I believe the technically correct answer would be: `ng-disabled` sets the `disabled` HTML attribute, so it will work with all HTML elements where `disabled` disables the control. Which then are the ones listed in the above link from @PSL .

Answer (score 1):

Per usage in the [ngDisabled docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

```
<INPUT
  ng-disabled="expression">
...
</INPUT>
```

An `<input />` element will be eligible for this directive. This includes semantic elements such as `<button>` `<select>` and `<textarea>` as well. For a list of all elements this directive can be applied to, see the other [form control](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#disabled-elements) elements.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: OP asked what elements ngDisabled can be applied to @charlietfl

Comment: what about all the others? Can disable about 8 different tags

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I tried explaining that only `<button>` and `<input />` elements can leverage ngDisabled. Have I missed any?

Comment: numerous other form controls yes

Comment: Do you mean input types? I'm not aware of any other semantic tag elements that qualify

Comment: see PSL link above for form controls

Comment: Ah nice yes I overlooked these! I'll add just for succinctness. Thanks